# Javascript: Store login credentials only if correct credentials are entered

Tags: javascript

I am trying to save the login credentials(like google does) for [site](https://myaccount.uscis.gov/); but i wish to first write it to console(just to check if im able to log correctly).

```
document.getElementById(''sign_in'').addEventListener(''click'',function()
{
    var userEmail = 
    document.getElementById(''user_email'').value;
    var userPwd = document.getElementById(''user_password'').value;
    console.log(userEmai,userPwd);
});
```

But the problem here is that, if the user inputs the wrong user_email/password, the same gets logged, and since the page refreshes on click of button, my javascript code would be wiped. 
Note - I had been using local storage(temporarily), and now moved to better solution.

Comment: You already know it, but i want to emphasize it: this is a bad idea. You should solve this with better session management.

Comment: Ohh, don't be such a downer @MarianTheisen. On a serious note: I completely agree with Marian. This is a very, VERY bad idea. Rather check out the concepts of json web tokens and how to properly use them for an "ongoing authentication" on the client side.

Comment: I concur with both of you @MarianTheisen, Philipp; however, as i said, the localstorage is a temporary idea. So, the problem of wrong username/password persists.

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to store the credential when and if only the authentication is successful.

What I mean is to wait for the authentication request to finish then store the creds on success (200 response code)

And, not also localstorage isn't the best way, you should never store any sensitive information into the browser. But you can implement JWT into your system as alternative.

Comment: The authentication request would be 200(succes), even for invalid password. The status is independent of the right credentials.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you will make some query to a database, you are not checking for what I see at any time if the user has been validated or not, try to use some if else. If you can add the part of the query to the database I can help you better thanks.

```
this._userService.login(this.user).subscribe(
  response => {
    this.identity = response.user;
    this.token = response.token;
    localStorage.setItem('identity', JSON.stringify(this.identity));
    localStorage.setItem('token', this.token);
    });
```

Comment: No query to database would be useful unless the credentials themselves are invalid:/

Comment: So where do you keep your registered users? :S

Comment: My point was- a)I am not looking to register/create the user when he's creating the account, so only page i have to save credentials is the signin page, where there's no question of registered user. b)why would I query DB if the credentials are wrong?
c) How do i know if the credentials are valid/not unless he signs in and is redirected  to next page if credentials are correct or the page refreshes and says invalid if credentials are wrong, either way my script wouldn't be there :?